# Is the pre-image of an compact set under an open continuous surjection also compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

We know that,

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces and $p:X\to Y$ be a $\color{red}{\text{closed}}$ continuous surjective map where $Y$ is compact. Let for all $y\in Y$, $p^{-1}(\{y\})$ is also compact. Prove that $X$ is compact.

The proof of this result can be found [here](http://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-3/section-26-compact-spaces/?t=problem-12-solution).

However, I was wondering if the following theorem also holds,

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces and $p:X\to Y$ be a $\color{red}{\text{open}}$ continuous surjective map where $Y$ is compact. Let for all $y\in Y$, $p^{-1}(\{y\})$ is also compact. Then $X$ is compact.

In case it is false, can someone give an counterexample to the above proposition? In can it is true, can someone give me an hint for the proof?

Comment: This is not true. Consider the map $p: [0,2\pi) \to S^1$, $t \mapsto e^{it}$.

Comment: @Sayantan Is that map open? I don't think $p([0,\pi))$ is open in $S^1$.

Comment: @kccu You are correct, it is not open. But one can change the domain to say $(-2\pi,2\pi)$. I guess it will work then.

Comment: @Sayantan Ah, okay I agree that works.